# How are users with insufficent reputation getting the Custodian badge?

Tags: bug, reputation, badges

So according to this badge's requirement, we need to complete at least one review task.

The lowest reputation requirement for a review task is 500. So can someone please tell me how a bunch of [users with less than 500 rep are somehow getting this badge](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/badges/99/custodian)?

I can't get access to the review tasks (since I lack sufficent reputation), but somehow a bunch of users with as little as one rep and hardly any activity on the site somehow have.

I don't know about anyone else, but something seems very wrong, possibly even broken somewhere.

Comment: You don't need to change the title to indicate the status of the question. Accepting an answer below indicates that the question is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users at any level of reputation can always review suggested edits made to their own posts.

Looking at the first handful of single-reputation users on the badge list, it looks like all of them have approved a suggested edit to their own post. This counts as a review task and awards the badge.

Comment: Ok, so my next stupid question is: how does one approve of a suggested edit to their own post? I can see the edit made to this question appear in my inbox here, but nowhere does an 'approve/deny' button or link appear.

Comment: When a suggested edit is made to your post you'll get an inbox notification with a link that will let you review it. However, "suggested edits" only come from users below 2000 reputation. At 2000 reputation, you gain the ability to make edits without approval (that's why you didn't get the ability to approve/deny my edit; I have more than the required reputation).

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for that.